# Custom String from ISO Compliant Date

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I am getting a date string as 2014-01-11-T00:00:00Z
I want to convert this date to 20140111 i.e YYYYMMDD it should be a string.

Any standard method/function to achieve above?

Comment: Oops Sorry I forgot to mention its Java.

Comment: It's Ok - you tagged it with `java`

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to"? If you just want to extract year, month and date from a string and put them in another string, 3 substrings and 3 string concatenations are enough, you don't need the burden of creating several Date objects.

Comment: Is that hyphen before the “T” a typo, `-T`?

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

Your date-time string, `2014-01-11-T00:00:00Z` is a bit weird as I have never seen such a date-time string where there is a hyphen (`-`) before `T`. For this kind of string, the following pattern meets the parsing requirement:

```
yyyy-M-d-'T'H:m:sXXX
```

Also, with `java.time` API, I recommend you replace `y` with `u` as explained in  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573). For the output string, you do NOT need to define any pattern as there already exists an inbuilt `DateTimeFormatter` for this pattern: `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d-'T'H:m:sXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2014-01-11-T00:00:00Z", dtfInput);
        System.out.println(odt);

        String output = odt.toLocalDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-01-11T00:00Z
20140111
```

**Note:**

1. Had your date-time string been [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant, you would NOT have needed to use a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly for parsing i.e. you could have simply parsed it as

```
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2014-01-11T00:00:00Z");
```

2. The `Z` in the date-time stands for Zulu which specifies UTC time (that has a timezone offset of `+00:00` hours) in ISO 8601 standard. Thus, this solution will also work for a date-time string like `2014-01-11-T00:00:00+02:00` which has a timezone offset of `+02:00` hours.
3. In case, you need a `java.util.Date` object from this object of `OffsetDateTime`, you can do so as follows:

```
    Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Note that the legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to `java.time` API. Just for the sake of completeness, I am providing you with a solution using the legacy API.

**Using the legacy API:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdfInput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d-'T'H:m:sXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);

        SimpleDateFormat sdfOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        sdfOutput.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));// Change it as required

        Date date = sdfInput.parse("2014-01-11-T00:00:00Z");

        String output = sdfOutput.format(date);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
20140111
```

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: It was about time someone posted the recommended answer to this 7 years old question. Thank you very much.

Comment: Whoever upvoted my comment, thanks, it’s better to upvote the answer to help other readers find it.

Answer (score 0):

Take this

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormat {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        Date inDate = inFormat.parse("2014-01-11-T00:00:00Z");

        SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        String output = outFormat.format(inDate);

        System.out.println("Date: " + output);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread for Date formatting in Java using Zoulou notation :

[Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Then create a new SimpleDateFormat using the "yyyyMMdd" format string.

Answer (score 0):

Here an improved version of given answer by @drkunibar:

```
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
inFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); // Z denotes UTC in ISO-8601
Date inDate = inFormat.parse("2014-01-11-T00:00:00Z");

SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
outFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("...")); // set your timezone explicitly!
String output = outFormat.format(inDate);

System.out.println("Date: " + output);
```

Note that the format YYYYMMDD is also ISO-8601-compliant (a so-called basic calendar date). The question you have to ask yourself is in which timezone you want to get your output. If in UTC you have to set "GMT", too. Without setting timezone it can happen that your output date differs from input UTC date by one day dependent where your default system timezone is (for example US is several hours behind UTC, in this case one calendar day before UTC midnight).

Comment: With all due respect , I recommend using `yyyy-M-d-'T'H:m:sXXX` in which `XXX` truly represents the timezone offset. The pattern, `yyyy-MM-dd-'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'` specifies `'Z'` merely as a character literal.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I absolutely know that the Z-literal denotes a zero offset. Therefore I have also set the time zone to zero in the input format to do the necessary compensation. Furthermore, your recommendation using XXX is surely well meant but please note the old date of my post in year 2014 where many Java versions did not yet recognize the new pattern letter X. So the whole answer is absolutely correct for those elder Java platforms and adequate for the question which explicitly wanted the old SimpleDateFormat-API. Now we have better APIs...

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** This Answer is now obsolete. See the modern solution using *java.time* in the [Answer by Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67344845/642706).

## Joda-Time

This date-time work is much easier with the Joda-Time 2.3 library.

```
String input = "2014-01-11T00:00:00Z";  // In standard ISO 8601 format.
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( input, DateTimeZone.UTC );  // Parse string into date-time object.
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.basicDate();  // Factory to make a formatter.
String output = formatter.print( dateTime );  // Generate string from date-Time object.
```

Comment: Although correct, I feel two things need to be addressed: (1) The pattern mentioned in the question is `2014-01-11-T00:00:00Z` and not `2014-01-11T00:00:00Z` (2) [*java.time* was released in Mar 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) (one month before you posted this answer) and therefore you should have used *java.time* API (at least in addition to Joda-Time, if not just *java.time* API). This is with all due respect, as I have mentioned many times that I've learnt so many things related to date-time API from contributors like you, Andreas, Ole V.V., Meno Hochschild etc.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash For (1) I consider that the hyphen before `T` was very likely a typo in the question.